# Dual Postgres Instances config_file issue

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.4, postgres-9.6

I have a sevrer that has an instance of postgres 9.4 I am using.
I installed another version of postgres (9.6), but have come across an issue.

To init the new db, I ran

> sudo -u postgres /usr/pgsql-9.6/bin/initdb -D /var/lib/pgsql/9.6/data/

But when I check the sql, I get the following.

```
sudo -u postgres /usr/pgsql-9.6/bin/psql
psql (9.6.9, server 9.4.18)
Type "help" for help.

postgres=# SHOW config_file;
               config_file               
-----------------------------------------
 /var/lib/pgsql/9.4/data/postgresql.conf
```

I can see it is using my 9.4, but I am unsure how to correct this issue, and have not managed to find any resources that indicate how to do so.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: The 9.4 postgres use the default port. I guess you set another one for postgres 9.6.  Connect to it with `psql -P xxxx` where xxxx is the 9.6 port number.

Comment: Well, I feel like an idiot. Please make that an answer, and I'll make sure to accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The 9.4 postgres use the default port and I guess you set another one for postgres 9.6.

Connect to it with psql -P xxxx where xxxx is the 9.6 port number.